# Questions about ` run` and `word` in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

The following code does what one would expect.

```
(run [ [b n init] -> (run (word "create-" b " " n " [" init " ]"))] "turtles" 3 "setxy 19 4")
```

It creates three turtles and puts them at (19, 4). I wanted to do something slimilar without quoting the initialization. So I tried:

```
(run [ [b n init] -> (run (word "create-" b " " n " " init ))] "turtles" 3 (list setxy -6 -4))
```

But I got an error message: `LIST expected 2 inputs on the right or any number of inputs when surrounded by parentheses.` Since list and its inputs are surrounded by parentheses, I imagine the problem is with using "setxy" without quotes.

It turns out that the following runs (to my surprise).

```
(run [ [b n  init] -> (run (word "create-" b " " n " " init ))] "turtles" 3 (list "setxy" -6 -7))
```

Since `(list "setxy" -6 -7)` produces `["setxy" -6 -7]` I don't understand why that happened.

To see what was going on I ran `word (list "setxy" -6 -7) ""` and got `"[setxy -6 -7]"`

How should I understand what `word` is doing? Why did it drop the quotes around `setxy`? Is the idea that since `word` produces a string, any embedded strings are essentially appended in place rather than treated as embedded strings? I would have expected a string with an embedded string to include quotation mark characters around the embedded string. If the embedded string itself has an embedded string, that would become ambiguous. But that would be as user issue.

Comment: At the command line, enter `show (word ["setxy" -6 -7])`. hth

Comment: I agree that the documentation should make clear and does not that `["1" 2 3] != (runresult (word ["1" 2 3]))`.

Comment: The documentation for NetLogo's primitives is hosted on GitHub: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/hexy/autogen/docs/dictionary.html.mustache#L8785-L8811. Pull requests for potential improvements would possibly be welcome...

Answer (score 1):

> How should I understand what word is doing?

Suppose you have the following list:

```
let xs ["a" "b" "c"]
```

Internally, this:

```
print (word xs)
```

is the equivalent of this:

```
print (word "[" (reduce [ [acc x] -> (word acc " " x) ] xs) "]")
```

In other words, `word` just runs itself on every element of the list and appends brackets at both ends and spaces in between.

(The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/hexy/netlogo-gui/src/main/prim/_word.java) and [here](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/hexy/parser-core/src/main/core/Dump.scala).)

> Why did it drop the quotes around setxy?

Is the fact that this results in `[a b c]` instead of `["a" "b" "c"]` a well thought out decision, or just a somewhat unintended consequence of the way that code was originally written in the late 90s? I, for one, can't say. Maybe someone else will have more insight.

If you want to use this quirk to build stringified code blocks, though, I'd say go right ahead. This behavior is unlikely to change any time soon...

Comment: I doubt there's much rhyme or reason here (I can confirm that these decisions date back to the 1990s). `[a b c]` is probably some kind of confused hangover from standard Logo dialects like Berkeley Logo, and from Lisp.